# limit result to one in object foreach loop, in_array does not work

Tags: php, object, break, strpos

I have a list of cities, these cities may exists once or repeated several times, or may not exists at all.

With php I want to check if city is in the foreach, and if exists print only one input out.

Below works perfect, print city only if exist, but repeats the existing:

```
  **Updated (added afterwards):**
$paradasarray= array(); 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($viajes); 
foreach ($xml->parada as $excursion) { 
  $paradasObject = new stdClass(); 
  $paradasObject->localidad = $excursion->localidad; 
  $paradasObject->localidad = str_replace('/<![CDATA[(.*)]]>/', '', 
  $paradasObject->localidad); $paradasarray[] = $paradasObject; 
} 
$paradasarray = json_encode($paradasarray); $paradasarray = 
json_decode($paradasarray); 

     **end updated**


foreach ($paradasarray as $parada) {
    if (strpos($parada->localidad, 'Benalmádena') !== false) {
        echo '<option value="Benalmádena Costa">Benalmádena Costa</option>';
    }
    if (strpos($parada->localidad, 'Estepona') !== false) {
        echo '<option value="Estepona">Estepona</option>';
    }
}
```

I have tried with break, however or I only get one of the two cities when I should get both, or none of them.

Comment: Use `array_unique`

Comment: Can we see what your sample input looks like?  Are you using `strpos()` because you **need to** perform a partial match on the element values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove duplicate value from your array so get `localidad` column of array using `array_column()` and remove duplicate values from it using `array_unique()`

```
$newParadasarray = array_unique(array_column($paradasarray, "localidad"));
```

So your code should changed to

```
$newParadasarray = array_unique(array_column($paradasarray, "localidad"));
foreach ($newParadasarray as $parada) {
    if (strpos($parada, 'Benalmádena') !== false)
        echo '<option value="Benalmádena Costa">Benalmádena Costa</option>';

    if (strpos($parada, 'Estepona') !== false)
        echo '<option value="Estepona">Estepona</option>';
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/pKYtq)

---

**Update:**

I see your full code so you can create an array contain only `localidad` values. and easily remove duplicate values from it using `array_unique`. Only add bottom code to your first loop (xml loop).

```
@$newParadasarray[] = $excursion->localidad;
```

And remove duplicate value after loop like this

```
$newParadasarray = array_unique($newParadasarray);
```

And loop through array to printing options

```
foreach ($newParadasarray as $parada) {
    if (strpos($parada, 'Benalmádena') !== false)
        echo '<option value="Benalmádena Costa">Benalmádena Costa</option>';

    if (strpos($parada, 'Estepona') !== false)
        echo '<option value="Estepona">Estepona</option>';
}
```

Comment: Don't work, maybe I should have posted full code. Its from an xml.
Before the foreach:
$paradasarray= array();
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($viajes);
foreach ($xml->parada as $excursion) {
 $paradasObject = new stdClass();
$paradasObject->localidad = $excursion->localidad;
 $paradasObject->localidad = str_replace('/<!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]>/', '', $paradasObject->localidad);
 $paradasarray[] = $paradasObject;
}
$paradasarray = json_encode($paradasarray);
  $paradasarray = json_decode($paradasarray);

Comment: @Helenp Please write all question details in the question itself.  This way the full story is all in the one predictable location for everyone's convenience.

Comment: Thanks, This works just perfect, however reorder the inputs.
Now I need to order them alfabethically

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
$cities = [];

foreach ($paradasarray as $parada) {
    // If the current city is not in our array i.e. if it hasn't been printed
    if (!in_array($parada->localidad, $cities)) {
         // print then push
         array_push($parada->localidad, $cities);
    }
}
```

This way you are keeping track of all the cities you have already printed.

**However**, I would actually amend this at a query level (if a query is involved) and filter them from there.

**Reading Material**

[`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `break` condition when 2 different matches are stored.  The beauty in declaring the `$result` array keys, is that if you encounter a duplicate qualifying value, it will overwrite the "group" element instead of generating a new element.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZecRC))

```
$paradasarray = [
    (object)['localidad' => 'Estepona whatever'],
    (object)['localidad' => 'something Benalmádena'],
    (object)['localidad' => 'Benalmádena foo'],
    (object)['localidad' => 'Estepona bar']
];

$result = [];
foreach ($paradasarray as $i => $parada) {
    if (strpos($parada->localidad, 'Benalmádena') !== false) {
        $result['Benalmádena'] = "Benalmádena Costa";
    } elseif (strpos($parada->localidad, 'Estepona') !== false) {
        $result['Estepona'] = 'Estepona';
    }
    if (count($result) == 2) {
        break;
    }
}

// you don't need to declare a value attribute if it matches the text
echo "<select>";
    echo "<option>" , implode("</option><option>", $result) , "</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

No matter how many elements are matched, you will either get:

0: an empty `<option></option>` tag in the select.
1: a single, filled option in the select
2: both filled options in the select

Comment: @Helenp This is how you implement the `break` and perform with high efficiency.